# Monitor long running task in c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, multithreading, postgresql

I need to create index on postgres database from c# application. I assume that I will use npgsql just to execute SQL. It may take some time to be completed and I want to monitor what is going on. The question is how to monitor it. Should it be separate thread, or task or any other option.

Also there is a risk that during that operation c# app will be closed., After recovery I would like to be able to check the status of index as well.

I will store some information in my configuration database for example:

```
indexName, status, startSqlTime
```

What would you recommend, how to attack that problem knowing that index creation may take a lot of time (hours).

Comment: I don't think there is any feedback from SQL during a CREATE INDEX, so you aren't going to be able to monitor 'progress'.

Comment: It's certainly possible (not easily) in SQL Server, e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139191/sql-server-how-to-track-progress-of-create-index-command so I imagine it might be possible in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11329/monitoring-progress-of-index-construction-in-postgresql

Comment: So maybe at least three is a way to run that create operatorom and don't wait for result. Just have another thread that would check the status once every minute or so?

Comment: You may watch this video and the second part. It explains quite well how to run backgrond tasks asynchronously:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2moh18sh5p4

Comment: Why do you need to add index from C#?